# Spark Job in Client Mode is throwing error

Tags: apache-spark

I am trying to run a Spark job in Server. It is not throwing error when I am running any normal `println` operation. I am unable to understand the error. 
I am trying to deploy the code in yarn client mode. Many has said to use `chmod 777` in warehouse directories, to disable/enable `.enableHiveSupport()` but it never works. Need help. I have tried a lot to run and deploy this code in client mode in by spark-submit command, its not working. This code is working like a charm in Eclipse but not by spark-submit. Need help. Thanks.

**Code:**

```
package com.issuer.pack3.spark
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.storage.StorageLevel._
import org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext

object SparkApplication3 {

  def main(args:Array[String])
    {
val warehouseLocation = "/hadoop/spark-2.2.1/spark-warehouse"
val sparksessionobject = SparkSession
   .builder()
   .master("local[*]")
   .appName("SparkSession1")
   .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", warehouseLocation)
   .config("spark.executor.memory", "10g")
   .config("spark.driver.memory","10g")
   .config("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", "10000")
   .config("spark.driver.maxResultSize", "200g")        
   .config("spark.memory.offHeap.enabled", "true")
   .config("spark.memory.offHeap.size", "200g")
   .config("spark.debug.maxToStringFields", "100")
// .enableHiveSupport()
   .getOrCreate()

val joined_acc_custinfo_trips = sparksessionobject.sqlContext.read.format("csv")
     .option("header", "true")
     .option("inferSchema", "true").load("/home/user/input/part-00000.csv")


joined_acc_custinfo_trips.registerTempTable("joined_acc_custinfo_trips") 

val query9 = "--SQL QUERY IS HERE--"
val res06 = sparksessionobject.sqlContext.sql(query9.toString) 
res06.repartition(1).write.json("/hadoop/OP/part1/")

     println("-------------------------------------END OF FIRST STAGE-------------------------------------------")
     println("-------------------------------------END OF FIRST STAGE-------------------------------------------")
     println("-------------------------------------END OF FIRST STAGE-------------------------------------------")
     println("-------------------------------------END OF FIRST STAGE-------------------------------------------")
     println("-------------------------------------END OF FIRST STAGE-------------------------------------------")



    }

}
```

**Error:**

```
[user@Analytic ~]$ spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode client --class "com.issuer.pack3.spark.SparkApplication3" /home/user/app2.jar
18/08/20 17:25:21 INFO spark.SparkContext: Running Spark version 2.2.1
18/08/20 17:25:21 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
18/08/20 17:25:21 INFO spark.SparkContext: Submitted application: SparkSession1
18/08/20 17:25:21 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: bhaskar
18/08/20 17:25:21 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: bhaskar
18/08/20 17:25:21 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to:
18/08/20 17:25:21 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to:
18/08/20 17:25:21 INFO spark.SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(bhaskar); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(bhaskar); groups with modify permissions: Set()
18/08/20 17:25:22 INFO util.Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriver' on port 40090.
18/08/20 17:25:22 INFO spark.SparkEnv: Registering MapOutputTracker
18/08/20 17:25:22 INFO spark.SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMaster
18/08/20 17:25:22 INFO storage.BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Using org.apache.spark.storage.DefaultTopologyMapper for getting topology information
18/08/20 17:25:22 INFO storage.BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: BlockManagerMasterEndpoint up
18/08/20 17:25:22 INFO storage.DiskBlockManager: Created local directory at /tmp/blockmgr-2af112f6-030a-4f01-91fc-8e69f1281fde
18/08/20 17:25:22 INFO memory.MemoryStore: MemoryStore started with capacity 200.4 GB
18/08/20 17:25:22 INFO spark.SparkEnv: Registering OutputCommitCoordinator
18/08/20 17:25:22 INFO util.log: Logging initialized @1480ms
18/08/20 17:25:22 INFO server.Server: jetty-9.3.z-SNAPSHOT
18/08/20 17:25:22 INFO server.Server: Started @1542ms
18/08/20 17:25:22 WARN util.Utils: Service 'SparkUI' could not bind on port 4040. Attempting port 4041.
18/08/20 17:25:22 INFO server.AbstractConnector: Started ServerConnector@5cad8b7d{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:4041}
18/08/20 17:25:22 INFO util.Utils: Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4041.
18/08/20 17:25:22 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@492fc69e{/jobs,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
18/08/20 17:25:22 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@6d2260db{/jobs/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
18/08/20 17:25:22 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@49bf29c6{/jobs/job,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
18/08/20 17:25:22 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@7668d560{/jobs/job/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
18/08/20 17:25:22 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@126be319{/stages,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
18/08/20 17:25:22 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@5c371e13{/stages/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
18/08/20 17:25:22 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@1e34c607{/stages/stage,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
18/08/20 17:25:22 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@9257031{/stages/stage/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
18/08/20 17:25:22 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@7726e185{/stages/pool,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
18/08/20 17:25:22 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@282308c3{/stages/pool/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
18/08/20 17:25:22 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@1db0ec27{/storage,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
18/08/20 17:25:22 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@d4ab71a{/storage/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
18/08/20 17:25:22 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@1af05b03{/storage/rdd,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
18/08/20 17:25:22 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@1ad777f{/storage/rdd/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
18/08/20 17:25:22 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@438bad7c{/environment,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
18/08/20 17:25:22 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@4fdf8f12{/environment/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
18/08/20 17:25:22 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@54f5f647{/executors,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
18/08/20 17:25:22 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@5a6d5a8f{/executors/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
18/08/20 17:25:22 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@315ba14a{/executors/threadDump,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
18/08/20 17:25:22 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@27f0ad19{/executors/threadDump/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
18/08/20 17:25:22 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@38d5b107{/static,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
18/08/20 17:25:22 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@77e2a6e2{/,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
18/08/20 17:25:22 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@199e4c2b{/api,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
18/08/20 17:25:22 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@2c1dc8e{/jobs/job/kill,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
18/08/20 17:25:22 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@4e7095ac{/stages/stage/kill,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
18/08/20 17:25:22 INFO ui.SparkUI: Bound SparkUI to 0.0.0.0, and started at http://192.168.70.13:4041
18/08/20 17:25:22 INFO spark.SparkContext: Added JAR file:/home/bhaskar/app2.jar at spark://192.168.70.13:40090/jars/app2.jar with timestamp 1534766122528
18/08/20 17:25:22 INFO executor.Executor: Starting executor ID driver on host localhost
18/08/20 17:25:22 INFO util.Utils: Successfully started service 'org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService' on port 41973.
18/08/20 17:25:22 INFO netty.NettyBlockTransferService: Server created on 192.168.70.13:41973
18/08/20 17:25:22 INFO storage.BlockManager: Using org.apache.spark.storage.RandomBlockReplicationPolicy for block replication policy
18/08/20 17:25:22 INFO storage.BlockManagerMaster: Registering BlockManager BlockManagerId(driver, 192.168.70.13, 41973, None)
18/08/20 17:25:22 INFO storage.BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager 192.168.70.13:41973 with 200.4 GB RAM, BlockManagerId(driver, 192.168.70.13, 41973, None)
18/08/20 17:25:22 INFO storage.BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager BlockManagerId(driver, 192.168.70.13, 41973, None)
18/08/20 17:25:22 INFO storage.BlockManager: Initialized BlockManager: BlockManagerId(driver, 192.168.70.13, 41973, None)
18/08/20 17:25:22 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@5560bcdf{/metrics/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
18/08/20 17:25:22 INFO internal.SharedState: Setting hive.metastore.warehouse.dir ('null') to the value of spark.sql.warehouse.dir ('/hadoop/spark-2.2.1/spark-warehouse').
18/08/20 17:25:22 INFO internal.SharedState: Warehouse path is '/hadoop/spark-2.2.1/spark-warehouse'.
18/08/20 17:25:22 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@4c98a6d5{/SQL,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
18/08/20 17:25:22 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@7f02251{/SQL/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
18/08/20 17:25:22 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@1bcf67e8{/SQL/execution,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
18/08/20 17:25:22 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@53692008{/SQL/execution/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
18/08/20 17:25:22 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@3a4ba480{/static/sql,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
18/08/20 17:25:23 INFO hive.HiveUtils: Initializing HiveMetastoreConnection version 1.2.1 using Spark classes.
18/08/20 17:25:23 INFO metastore.HiveMetaStore: 0: Opening raw store with implemenation class:org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore
18/08/20 17:25:23 INFO metastore.ObjectStore: ObjectStore, initialize called
18/08/20 17:25:23 INFO DataNucleus.Persistence: Property hive.metastore.integral.jdo.pushdown unknown - will be ignored
18/08/20 17:25:23 INFO DataNucleus.Persistence: Property datanucleus.cache.level2 unknown - will be ignored
18/08/20 17:25:25 INFO metastore.ObjectStore: Setting MetaStore object pin classes with hive.metastore.cache.pinobjtypes="Table,StorageDescriptor,SerDeInfo,Partition,Database,Type,FieldSchema,Order"
18/08/20 17:25:25 INFO DataNucleus.Datastore: The class "org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.model.MFieldSchema" is tagged as "embedded-only" so does not have its own datastore table.
18/08/20 17:25:25 INFO DataNucleus.Datastore: The class "org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.model.MOrder" is tagged as "embedded-only" so does not have its own datastore table.
18/08/20 17:25:26 INFO DataNucleus.Datastore: The class "org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.model.MFieldSchema" is tagged as "embedded-only" so does not have its own datastore table.
18/08/20 17:25:26 INFO DataNucleus.Datastore: The class "org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.model.MOrder" is tagged as "embedded-only" so does not have its own datastore table.
18/08/20 17:25:26 INFO metastore.MetaStoreDirectSql: Using direct SQL, underlying DB is DERBY
18/08/20 17:25:26 INFO metastore.ObjectStore: Initialized ObjectStore
18/08/20 17:25:26 WARN metastore.ObjectStore: Version information not found in metastore. hive.metastore.schema.verification is not enabled so recording the schema version 1.2.0
18/08/20 17:25:26 WARN metastore.ObjectStore: Failed to get database default, returning NoSuchObjectException
18/08/20 17:25:26 INFO metastore.HiveMetaStore: Added admin role in metastore
18/08/20 17:25:26 INFO metastore.HiveMetaStore: Added public role in metastore
18/08/20 17:25:26 INFO metastore.HiveMetaStore: No user is added in admin role, since config is empty
18/08/20 17:25:26 INFO metastore.HiveMetaStore: 0: get_all_databases
18/08/20 17:25:26 INFO HiveMetaStore.audit: ugi=bhaskar ip=unknown-ip-addr      cmd=get_all_databases
18/08/20 17:25:27 INFO metastore.HiveMetaStore: 0: get_functions: db=default pat=*
18/08/20 17:25:27 INFO HiveMetaStore.audit: ugi=bhaskar ip=unknown-ip-addr      cmd=get_functions: db=default pat=*
18/08/20 17:25:27 INFO DataNucleus.Datastore: The class "org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.model.MResourceUri" is tagged as "embedded-only" so does not have its own datastore table.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error while instantiating 'org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder':
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$.org$apache$spark$sql$SparkSession$$instantiateSessionState(SparkSession.scala:1062)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$$anonfun$sessionState$2.apply(SparkSession.scala:137)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$$anonfun$sessionState$2.apply(SparkSession.scala:136)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sessionState$lzycompute(SparkSession.scala:136)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sessionState(SparkSession.scala:133)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.<init>(DataFrameReader.scala:689)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.read(SparkSession.scala:645)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.read(SQLContext.scala:504)
        at com.issuer.pack3.spark.SparkApplication3$.main(SparkApplication3.scala:58)
        at com.issuer.pack3.spark.SparkApplication3.main(SparkApplication3.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:775)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:205)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:119)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.ConnectException: Call From Analytic/192.168.70.13 to localhost:8020 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused;
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.withClient(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:106)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.databaseExists(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:194)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState.externalCatalog$lzycompute(SharedState.scala:105)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState.externalCatalog(SharedState.scala:93)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder.externalCatalog(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:39)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder.catalog$lzycompute(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:54)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder.catalog(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder.catalog(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:35)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.BaseSessionStateBuilder.build(BaseSessionStateBuilder.scala:289)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$.org$apache$spark$sql$SparkSession$$instantiateSessionState(SparkSession.scala:1059)
        ... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.ConnectException: Call From Analytic/192.168.70.13 to localhost:8020 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:522)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.<init>(HiveClientImpl.scala:191)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.IsolatedClientLoader.createClient(IsolatedClientLoader.scala:264)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveUtils$.newClientForMetadata(HiveUtils.scala:362)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveUtils$.newClientForMetadata(HiveUtils.scala:266)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.client$lzycompute(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:66)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.client(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:65)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$databaseExists$1.apply$mcZ$sp(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:195)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$databaseExists$1.apply(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:195)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$databaseExists$1.apply(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:195)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.withClient(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:97)
        ... 28 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Call From Analytic/192.168.70.13 to localhost:8020 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapWithMessage(NetUtils.java:792)
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:732)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1479)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1412)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:229)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy19.getFileInfo(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.getFileInfo(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:771)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:191)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy20.getFileInfo(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.getFileInfo(DFSClient.java:2108)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$22.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1305)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$22.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1301)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:1317)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.exists(FileSystem.java:1426)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.createRootHDFSDir(SessionState.java:596)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.createSessionDirs(SessionState.java:554)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:508)
        ... 42 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:206)
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:531)
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:495)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupConnection(Client.java:614)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupIOstreams(Client.java:712)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.access$2900(Client.java:375)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getConnection(Client.java:1528)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1451)
        ... 62 more
18/08/20 17:25:27 INFO spark.SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
18/08/20 17:25:27 INFO server.AbstractConnector: Stopped Spark@5cad8b7d{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:4041}
18/08/20 17:25:27 INFO ui.SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://192.168.70.13:4041
18/08/20 17:25:27 INFO spark.MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint stopped!
18/08/20 17:25:27 INFO memory.MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared
18/08/20 17:25:27 INFO storage.BlockManager: BlockManager stopped
18/08/20 17:25:27 INFO storage.BlockManagerMaster: BlockManagerMaster stopped
18/08/20 17:25:27 INFO scheduler.OutputCommitCoordinator$OutputCommitCoordinatorEndpoint: OutputCommitCoordinator stopped!
18/08/20 17:25:27 INFO spark.SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext
18/08/20 17:25:27 INFO util.ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
18/08/20 17:25:27 INFO util.ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-739175a5-4864-4fd0-8e1d-a22ff371f821
[user@Analytic ~]$
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use below spark config while creating the spark session.

```
 .config("hive.metastore.uris", "placeyoururi")
```

or you can pass the hive-site.xml as below in the spark-submit.

```
--files configpath/hive-site.xml
```

Also use .enableHiveSupport() for both approaches.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Yes, replace your hive meta store in the config. You can get the hive metasore details from ambari or hive-site.xml.  

.config("hive.metastore.uris", "placeyoururi")

Comment: I will try tomorrow. Please keep in touch. I will accept and upvote your answer. Thanks for your reply

Comment: It is throwing error `DataNucleus.Datastore: The class "org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.model.MResourceUri" is tagged as "embedded-only" so does not have its own datastore table.`

Comment: Are you using hive-site.xml or hive metastore uri in code ? Can you share the spark submit command? Also please verify the hive metastore uri from Ambari ?

Comment: `spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode client --class "com.issuer.pack3.spark.SparkApplication3" --files /hadoop/apache-hive-2.2.0/conf/hive-site.xml /home/bhaskar/app2.jar`

Comment: `val warehouseLocation = "/hadoop/spark-2.2.1/spark-warehouse"
val metastore = "/hadoop/apache-hive-2.2.0/conf/hive-site.xml"
val sparksessionobject = SparkSession
   .builder()
   .master("local[*]")
   .appName("SparkSession1")
.
.
.
   .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", warehouseLocation)
   .config("hive.metastore.uris", "metastore")`

Comment: Yes it's the same I have mentioned above

Comment: I have observed that hive shell is not starting

Comment: .config("hive.metastore.uris", "metastore")
val metastore = "/hadoop/apache-hive-2.2.0/conf/hive-site.xml"
we should should not pass the hive-site.xml in the code. Please pass the value in the hive-site.xml
it will be like thrift://address:9083

Comment: Can you remove the .config("hive.metastore.uris", "metastore") and pass only hive-site.xml and try?

Comment: I have removed `.config("hive.metastore.uris", "metastore") ` and ran but still the error is present.
In in the hive-site.xml where it will be like thrift://address:9083  ?

Comment: Do you have the solution dear?

Comment: Can you try to include this in spark-submit like below
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=dirPath;spark-submit ....